# setting up local server in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to set up a localhost server to test my site on in sql server 2005. I just installed sql server 2005 and I have never set up a database in this before. There is a login screen and I tried everything and it will not let me log into anything. What are the steps I need to do to get this to work. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error message and it was resolved when i put server name as "(local)\SQLEXPRESS" (SQLEXPRESS is the default named instance for SQL Server installation. If you have changed it you can use that instead of this) and keeping windows authentication as the default authentication method.

Regards,
Ashwin Kaul

Answer (score 1):

Aren't sql server 2005 services stopped by default? Check in Services to see if the SQL SERVER service is started. Also since you mention localhost you won't need to configure the sql server surface area to include remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the free SQL 2005 Express edition the default name of the instance you need to connect to is "SQLEXPRESS" If you are logged into your computer as an administrator then you should be able to access your database with Windows Authentication. So your connection info should look something like [this](https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/111296/Forum/Example1.PNG):

[image: example.]

SQL comes with a built in system admin account "sa". You can also try logging in with SQL authentication like [this](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/111296/Forum/Example2.PNG):

[example. http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/111296/Forum/Example2.PNG](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/111296/Forum/Example2.PNG)

The password you will have had to of setup during the install of the SQL server.

You may also want to check your connection parameters in the SQL Configuration manager

If you still have problems logging into the database engine then I might suggest reinstalling SQL and make sure you install without "Hide Advanced Features" unchecked. It's unchecked by default in the Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- sql2005 is installed on your localhost
- u can connect to it via Query analyzer or Sql Server Management Studio?
- when the login prompt starts up, u have two options for authentication ->  Windows authentication or Sql Server Authentication.

If those assumptions are all correct, then try connecting via the Windows Authentication option. If that fails, then try the Sql Server Authentation and use the username 'sa' (no quotes), password leave empty.

does that work? also, post some links to screenshots so we can see exactly what you see, to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

What error message are you getting?

If you named the instance, you have to connect to "localhost\INSTANCE" or "(local)\INSTANCE" or ".\INSTANCE" where INSTANCE is the name you gave at install time.